# Where is the mistake in this proof related to linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have the following statement to prove:

> Let $T$ a linear map such that $T:U\to V$ and $\{u_i\}_{i=1}^n$ a
> linearly independent subset of $U$. Prove that if $T$ is injective
> then $\{T(u_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ is also linearly independent.

Well, my proof was:

Since $\{u_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is linearly independent, then we have $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iu_i=0$ with unique scalars $a_i=0 \forall i \in [1,n]$.

So, applying $T$ to both sides, we have:

$$T\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iu_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iT(u_i)=T(0)=0$$ so, since the zero vector written as linear combination of $T(u_i)$ have unique scalars $a_i=0 \forall i \in [1,n]$ implies that $\{T(u_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ is linearly independent.

I know that this is false, since we can create an unique linear map $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that

$T(1,0,0)=(2,2,2), T(0,1,0)=(2,2,2), T(0,0,1)=(2,2,2)$ that contradicts my result. So, where is my mistake?

Comment: This $T$  is not an injective map.

Comment: You didn't use that $T$ is injective. You should instead start with $\sum \alpha_i T(u_i) = 0$, then use injectivity of $T$.

Comment: and the fact that $T(0)=0$ is the only posibility for a linear injective map

Comment: @TitoEliatron why you say that? I know that every linear maps $T:U\to V$ takes $0_U$ to $0_V$

Comment: I took $T(0) = 0$ not $0 \implies T(0)$

Comment: I say that if $T$ is injective, $T(u)=0 \Rightarrow u=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not follow from the fact that $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n=0$ are the unique scalars such that $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iu_i=0$ that they are the unique scalars such that $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iT(u_i)=0$. If, say, $T\colon\Bbb R^2\longrightarrow\Bbb R^2$ is defined by $T(x,y)=(x,0)$, if $u_1=(1,0)$ and if $u_2=(0,1)$, then indedd $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$ are the unique scalars such that $\alpha_1u_1+\alpha_2u_2=0$, but if you take $\alpha_1=0$ and $\alpha_1=1$, you will also have $\alpha_1T(u_1)+\alpha_2T(u_2)=0$. Of course, this map $T$ is *not* injective.

Comment: So, scalars works uniquely for the $\{u_i\}_{i=1}^n$ set, but not necessarily are unique for $$\{T(u_i)\}_{i=1}^n$$. Thanks.